# quickest way to invite a friend via gmail or facebook?

Tags: facebook, gmail, contacts

i'm trying the find the quickest way to implement a simple feature that allows someone to invite a facebook or gmail friend from my website.

so basically a user on my website gets to a certain page and then has the option to "invite a friend".  what i want is the ability to quickly and easily choose from a list of their facebook friends to invite OR contacts in their gmail.  ideally they would start typing their name and it would auto complete with their gmail contact or facebook.  obviously there's nothing that does both, but i'm wondering if such a thing is even possible with either gmail contacts or facebook friends?

possible solution for google?

http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/poco/1.0/developers_guide.html

Comment: Sure it's possible. Both facebook and google have API's you can make use of.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides the 'Send' button for this purpose: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/   [edit] There's also a combined Like + Send button - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ [/edit]
it allows users to send a link to your page via Facebook messages, or by email to any email address

With the right meta tags ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ ) you control how the recipient sees the link, and get Insights on the share activity of your page